# Is it possible in Flutter to make dialer app on flutter, that can be choosed in settings as a default? And Is it possible to deny incoming calls?

Tags: android, flutter

I need to make dialer app, that:
1) can be choosed as a default android dialer in phone settings
2) should automatically call to some numbers without using any other app
3) can deny incoming calls and after save somewhere(cache or server, doesn't matter) this incoming number
Are this 3 points even possible to make using Flutter?
If yes, what can i use to do it?

Comment: You are asking two different questions here. Please mention what you have understood from your own research as it might help us answer better and quickly.

Comment: You might have to write native android code to do both of those.